NextJs next-auth Microsoft Entra ID authentication issue
I have a NextJS 14 Project and try to integrate Microsoft Entra ID for authentication. Since my project has next-auth already I decided to follow the official document to implement the Microsoft Entra ID authentication, unfortunately I keep getting the server error page after the auth code received. My understanding is once I get the auth code, it will be used to get the auth token but I can't find any document in next-auth.
The erros shows in NextJS console is
 [auth][details]: {
      "provider": "microsoft-entra-id"
    }
    error {
      error: 'invalid_client',
      error_description: "AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented. Trace ID: 797e6819-xxxx-4b04-9add-a1edxxxxxx Correlation ID: xxxxx41b-2df5-4d20-9bc2-ede1071e2dc6 Timestamp: 2024-08-19 04:38:50Z",
      error_codes: [ 700025 ],
      timestamp: '2024-08-19 04:38:50Z',
      trace_id: '797e6819-xxxx-4b04-9add-a1ed103e6400',
      correlation_id: 'xxxxx641b-2df5-4d20-9bc2-ede1071e2dc6'
    }
    [auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
    [auth][cause]: Error: TODO: Handle OIDC response body error


Can anyone familiar with the auth process help on it? Thanks!

The issue has been resolved when I switch my registered app from SPA to Web. This link helps a lot https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6133

Ensure that your application code does not include a client_secret or client_assertion when making the authentication request. Public clients should rely on other authentication methods like the authorization code flow with PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange).
